# Where did Kubernetes Security context runAsUser 1000 come from?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I learnt that to run a container as rootless, you need to specify either the SecurityContext:runAsUser 1000 or specify the USER directive in the DOCKERFILE.

Question on this is that there is no UID 1000 on the Kubernetes/Docker host system itself.

I learnt before that Linux User Namespacing allows a user to have a different UID outside it's original NS.

Hence, how does UID 1000 exist under the hood? Did the original root (UID 0) create a new user namespace which is represented by UID 1000 in the container?

What happens if we specify UID 2000 instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this answer helps you

> I learnt that to run a container as rootless, you need to specify
> either the SecurityContext:runAsUser 1000 or specify the USER
> directive in the DOCKERFILE

You are correct except in `runAsUser: 1000`. you can specify any UID, not only `1000`. Remember any UID you want to use (`runAsUser: UID`), that `UID` should already be there!

---

Often, base images will already have a user created and available but leave it up to the development or deployment teams to leverage it. For example, the official Node.js image comes with a user named node at UID `1000` that you can run as, but they do not explicitly set the current user to it in their Dockerfile. We will either need to configure it at runtime with a `runAsUser` setting or change the current user in the image using a `derivative Dockerfile`.

```yaml
runAsUser: 1001          # hardcode user to non-root if not set in Dockerfile
runAsGroup: 1001         # hardcode group to non-root if not set in Dockerfile
runAsNonRoot: true       # hardcode to non-root. Redundant to above if Dockerfile is set USER 1000
```

Remmeber that `runAsUser` and `runAsGroup` **ensures** container processes do not run as the `root` user but don’t rely on the `runAsUser` or `runAsGroup` settings to guarantee this. Be sure to also set `runAsNonRoot: true`.

---

Here is full example of `securityContext`:

```yaml
# generic pod spec that's usable inside a deployment or other higher level k8s spec

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod

spec:

  containers:

      # basic container details
    - name: my-container-name
      # never use reusable tags like latest or stable
      image: my-image:tag
      # hardcode the listening port if Dockerfile isn't set with EXPOSE
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP

      readinessProbe:        # I always recommend using these, even if your app has no listening ports (this affects any rolling update)
        httpGet:             # Lots of timeout values with defaults, be sure they are ideal for your workload
          path: /ready
          port: 8080
      livenessProbe:         # only needed if your app tends to go unresponsive or you don't have a readinessProbe, but this is up for debate
        httpGet:             # Lots of timeout values with defaults, be sure they are ideal for your workload
          path: /alive
          port: 8080

      resources:             # Because if limits = requests then QoS is set to "Guaranteed"
        limits:
          memory: "500Mi"    # If container uses over 500MB it is killed (OOM)
          #cpu: "2"          # Not normally needed, unless you need to protect other workloads or QoS must be "Guaranteed"
        requests:
          memory: "500Mi"    # Scheduler finds a node where 500MB is available
          cpu: "1"           # Scheduler finds a node where 1 vCPU is available

      # per-container security context
      # lock down privileges inside the container
      securityContext:
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false # prevent sudo, etc.
        privileged: false               # prevent acting like host root
  
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 600 # default is 30, but you may need more time to gracefully shutdown (HTTP long polling, user uploads, etc)

  # per-pod security context
  # enable seccomp and force non-root user
  securityContext:

    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault   # enable seccomp and the runtimes default profile

    runAsUser: 1001          # hardcode user to non-root if not set in Dockerfile
    runAsGroup: 1001         # hardcode group to non-root if not set in Dockerfile
    runAsNonRoot: true       # hardcode to non-root. Redundant to above if Dockerfile is set USER 1000
```

---

sources:

- [Kubernetes Pod Specification Good Defaults](https://github.com/BretFisher/podspec)
- [Configure a Security Context for a Pod or Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context)
- [10 Kubernetes Security Context settings you should understand](https://snyk.io/blog/10-kubernetes-security-context-settings-you-should-understand/)

Answer (score 0):

Something at the container layer calls the [**setuid**(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) system call with that numeric user ID.  There's no particular requirement to "create" a user; if you are able to call `setuid()` at all, you can call it with any numeric uid you want.

You can demonstrate this with plain Docker pretty easily.  The `docker run -u` option takes any numeric uid, and you can `docker run -u 2000` and your container will (probably) still run.  It's common enough to `docker run -u $(id -u)` to run a container with the same numeric user ID as the host user even though that uid doesn't exist in the container's `/etc/passwd` file.

At a Kubernetes layer this is a little less common.  A container can't usefully access host files in a clustered environment (...on which host?) so there's no need to have a user ID matching the host's.  If the image already sets up a non-root user ID, you should be able to just use it as-is without setting it at the Kubernetes layer.